# How to use Data from an array in another class & method?

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods

I've got a class named "User" which has a method that makes the User type his name. This name is saved in an array that is empty at first.

Question is, how can I use this "stored" name in another class (I want to show the name in this other class)

Here's what I've got (Sorry for the spanish lol)

```
public class Usuario {
    private Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String Usuario[] = new String[20];
    private int Posicion = 0;
    private int punteo;

public void Datos() {
    System.out.println("Ingresa tu nombre");

    if(Usuario[Posicion] == null) {
        this.Usuario[0] = entrada.nextLine();
        Posicion++;
    }

}
public String Usuario() {
    return Usuario[Posicion-1];
}
```

And I want to use the name (`Usuario[Posicion-1]`) for example in a class like this:

```
public class Score extends Usuario {
    Usuario usr = new Usuario();
    String[] Name = new String[20];

    public void Score () {
        Name[0]=usr.Usuario();

        System.out.println("------------Scores ------------------");
        System.out.println("    Name          "+ "            Score");
        for(int i=0;i<11;i++) {
            System.out.println(i+".- " + " "+Name[0] +"                        200 ");
        }
    }
}
```

But Everytime I try to retrieve this data in this class I get a "null" value or an "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1" error, which makes me believe that I can't use the information from the array in another class :(

I'd appreciate any help. (also Sorry for the not-so-good english).

Comment: You are wrong at several places. That is not the way to get inputs from user.

Comment: Instead of creating name Array, your should think of making `User` object Array.

Comment: First you shouldn't use the name of the class as the name of a getter. Second, your position starts at zero and, on your `Usuario` method you're always subtracting 1 to it.

Comment: Where is your main method that runs this code?

Answer (score 0):

Each new version of a class or an object is not going to have the same values.

you will have to get the name from the object User.name then set it in your other object secondObject.name = User.name